# Generating very large prime numbers and their generator modulo N in php

Tags: php, optimization, primes

I recently came up with the idea to attempt generating ungodly large prime numbers and their generators modulo N in php. I don't know much about number theory and just wanted to get some comments to see if this code should be sucessful. The output is just directed to a file at the moment because I didn't want to wast time on making it nice until I got the fundamentals right.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(150);                                        #keeps us from reaching max execution so soon. Giant primes take time to find
$bits               = 32;                                   #*32 for how many bits will be in the smaller prime, *64 for how many bits will be in larger prime
$attempts           = 300;                                  #maximum number of trys to find a safe prime
$prime_fail         = true;
for($i = 0; $i < $attempts; $i++){
    $prime          = gmp_random($bits);                    #generate a large random number
    $prime          = gmp_nextprime($prime);                #find the next prime
    $safe_prime     = gmp_add(gmp_mul($prime, 2), 1);           #manufacture the bigger prime candidate so we can make sure it is indeed prime
    if( gmp_prob_prime($safe_prime) == 0 ){
        $prime_fail = true;                                 #set the pimality fail flag
        $safe_prime = NULL;                                 #number was not prime for sure
    }else{
        $prime_fail = false;                                #did not fail probable primality
        break;                                              #no use going on, we found a safe prime
    }
}
if(!$prime_fail){
    #we found the safe prime we were looking for so lets get the generator

    $generator_found            = false;
    $g_upper_limit              = 10;                       #this limits the highest value that g will be selected at, this method will always return the smalles g possible for convinience
    $onemod = gmp_intval(gmp_mod(1, $safe_prime));          #go ahead and calculate 1 % N just to make sure the math of the proceedure is clear.

    for($g = 1; $g <= $g_upper_limit; $g++){
        #For N where N is prime and N=2p+1 where p is prime
        #g is a generator mod N if
        #g^((N-1)/2) != 1 % N and g^((N-1)/p) != 1 % N
        #since N = 2p +1, N-1 = 2p
        #g^(2p/2) != 1 % N and g^(2p/p) != 1 % N
        #g^p != 1 % N and g^2 != 1 % N
        #remember that the = and != are congruent and not congruent
        #that means we need to use modulo exponentiation as congruency measeures if the remainder is the same between two operations
        if(gmp_intval(gmp_powm($g, $prime, $safe_prime)) != $onemod && gmp_intval(gmp_powm($g, 2, $safe_prime)) != $onemod){
            $generator_found    = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!$generator_found){
        #failed to find generator
        die("<h1 style='text-align: center;'>failed to find generator modulo N. Please run setup again.</h1>");
        exit;
    }

    #we have both so lets do the setup
    $setupfile      = "Prime.inc";
    $safe_prime     = gmp_strval($safe_prime, 16);
    $g              = "$g\n";
    @touch($setupfile) or die("<h1 style='text-align: center;'>Unable to create setup file at this time. Please rerun setup.</h1>");
    @$fh = fopen($setupfile, 'x') or die("<h1 style='text-align: center;'>Unable to write to setup file/setup file already exists.(Prime.inc)</h1>");
    @fwrite($fh, $g) or die("<h1 style='text-align: center;'>Unable to write generator to setup file.(Prime.inc)</h1>");
    @fwrite($fh, $safe_prime) or die("<h1 style='text-align: center;'>Unable to write prime to setup file.(Prime.inc)</h1>");
    @fclose($fh);
    echo "<h1 style='text-align: center;'>Prime.inc created and populated sucessfully.</h1>";
}else{
    #we did not find the safe prime we were looking for
    echo "<h1 style='text-align: center;'>Setup Unsuccessful</h1><br />";
    echo "<p style='text-align: center;'>Please Rerun Setup</p>";
}
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1, I'd extract out a custom `die` function:

```
function myDie($msg) {
    $prefix = "<h1 style='text-align: center;'>";
    $postfix = "</h1>";
    die($prefix . $postfix . $msg);
}
```

2, Maybe you should lock the `$setupfile`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293601/php-and-concurrent-file-access

3, The `exit` never runs, so it's unnecessary:

```
if(!$generator_found){
    #failed to find generator
    die("<h1 style='text-align: center;'>failed to ... Please run setup again.</h1>");
    exit; // remove it
}
```

4, If you have a variable for the file name, use that variable in the error messages too:

```
$setupfile      = "Prime.inc";
...
@$fh = fopen($setupfile, 'x') or myDie("Unable to ... (" . $setupfile . ")");
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a global conditional operator is much more advantageous to use the boundary conditions

For example:

```
if ($prime_fail){
  message_error(PRIME_FAIL);
  exit;
}

$generator_found = false;
$g_upper_limit = 10; 
$onemod = gmp_intval(gmp_mod(1, $safe_prime));
// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not worth an answer but as everything else as been said...

You can make things a bit more concise in :

```
$prime_fail         = true;
for($i = 0; $i < $attempts; $i++){
    $prime          = gmp_random($bits);              # generate a large random number
    $prime          = gmp_nextprime($prime);          # find the next prime
    $safe_prime     = gmp_add(gmp_mul($prime, 2), 1); # manufacture the bigger prime candidate so we can make sure it is indeed prime
    if( gmp_prob_prime($safe_prime) == 0 ){
        $prime_fail = true;                           # set the pimality fail flag
        $safe_prime = NULL;                           # number was not prime for sure
    }else{
        $prime_fail = false;                          # did not fail probable primality
        break;                                        # no use going on, we found a safe prime
    }
}
if(!$prime_fail){
```

By :

- assigning to `$prime` the value you want it to have
- getting rid of `$prime_fail` as the value of `$safe_prime` should be enough.

Result is :

```
for($i = 0; $i < $attempts; $i++){
    $prime      = gmp_nextprime(gmp_random($bits)); # find the prime after a large random number
    $safe_prime = gmp_add(gmp_mul($prime, 2), 1);   # manufacture a bigger prime candidate
    if(gmp_prob_prime($safe_prime)){                # make sure it is indeed prime
        break;                                      # no use going on, we found a safe prime
    }
    $safe_prime = NULL;                             #number was not prime for sure
}
if($safe_prime){
```

As for the maths, I wish I could check the validity but I have no background in that field.